# C applications freeze when connecting to servers

Tags: c, linux, sockets, console, freeze

Hello and thanks in advance for any help.I am trying to make simple socket connecting programs in C.After every connect() function with correct parameters,i have a printf("connected").But even though i get no error for the connection attempt,i don't see the "connected" message either.All i see is a black console,no messages,no errors and it never exits

Could this be caused because i'm running the application from virtualbox?

ok added code directly,this is taken right from a tutorial website so it should work.But in my case it just waits forever for connection i guess

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How long is "forever"?  The `connect()` call should time out.

Comment: seems yes,after all it timed out at about 1 minute.I guess so at least because i got connection failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect` function can have a freeze-like comportment (but always timeout after some time) if you are trying to connect to an address that doesn't exists or that is not listening on this port. It appears to be the case.

Try to run a simple server using `nc -lk [your port here]` and to connect to `127.0.0.1` (localhost) to your port.

EDIT: Do not use a port from 0 to 1023. You need to be a root user to bind these. Try another one, like 4242.

Comment: ok this seems to have worked.So a lack of any message whatsoever is an attempt to find the IP?

Comment: Btw i tried connecting from VM machine to 127.0.0.1 port 80 but didnt work.But connecting to my host PC on port 80 worked.As far as i know i am not running any http server on the host machine

Comment: Do not try to bind a port on your own machine from port 0 to 1023. You would need root rights. Try on any another port, like 4242.

Comment: ok thanks a lot.i have only one question left,if you could bother to answer it.I sent a http request to google but i only got text info.Shouldn't what i get be a html file saved in the program directory?

Comment: If you are directly using sockets as file descriptors, you can only have text fluxes. So if you want to save it in a file, you will have to do it yourself, creating the file, reading the socket, and writing data it in the file.

Comment: damn this is gonna be hard then.i am supposed to send any file from server to client,so if a client want's something like an mp3 i am screwed.Anyway,thanks a lot for all the help,i appreciate it

Comment: To save data from file, you can send it part by part. One usually way is to send your file by block of 4096 bytes, but before it precise the complete size of the file (for the client to know when to stop). If you think my answers were sufficient, you can validate it with the green symbol before my score arrows :)